# Showing icon label on mouse hover only

Tags: usability, user-expectation, usability-testing, ux-field, ux-designer

I'm developing a data table and I'm having trouble fitting all the columns on one screen. My main goal is to reduce the width of the table, and one of my ideas were to remove the icon label and show it on hover similar to option 2 in this image below:

[image]

I know that as a ux designer, we should try to avoid using icons without labels, but in this case is hiding the label ok? Our customers should be tech savvy enough to understand what the icon means and the column title for this icon is "Status", so I believe most will be able to determine the meaning from those clues alone.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the behavior, but I consider myself a tech-savvy person, and I wouldn't recognize that icon as offline. Also, consider what happens on mobile (assuming it applies)

Comment: @Devin Does not apply to mobile. This is a dashboard used by businesses to monitor their devices, so the entire function of the software is to monitor device status. I feel given the purpose of the product, the meaning of the icon would be straight forward

Comment: Agree with the above! I would just add to think about the mobile view here, since showing the tooltip on hover won't be an option. If you think that works, then that's probably the best option.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the best possible way to do it without disturbing the user experience. User's are familiar with hovering icons to get the tooltip for the icons they don't know the functionality of. I have attached a simple reference for better understanding. Just make sure that you use standard icons that users are more familiar with and use the same size and positioning of tooltip for an attractive no clutter view.

[image]